# Is combining FETCH_OBJ And FETCH_ASSOC in PDO fetchAll() possible?

Tags: php, pdo, fetchall

I am trying to migrate from mysqli procedural to PDO because my website was halfway, half in pdo, and the rest in mysqli procedural, now I want to shift to PDO completely. Here is an example of the code I run

```
$rowNum = 0;
foreach ($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $row) {
  $rowNum = $rowNum + 1;
   $dbUsername = $row['Username'];
}
if ($row>0) {
    echo $dbUsername;
}
```

But in some scenarios, the code gives me an error that `trying to get property  'Username' of non-object`

I know it was possible to use only `($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

But doing this `($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` becomes a need as some context of the code I'm modifying use the symbol like `$row->Usename` and the other use `$row['Username`'], How can I make it accept both modes as shown above?

I tried to use PDO:: FETCH_BOTH but the problem persists.

Comment: `some context of the code I'm modifying use the symbol like $row->Usename and the other use $row['Username']` - How it's even possible? I mean, neither mysqli or PDO would even allow that, so it means it **never** worked. How did it make into your code?

Comment: @Dharman or while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)) :)

Answer (score 2):

As @YourCommonSense pointed out in his comment, you can use `PDO::FETCH_LAZY` to accomplish this. However, you cannot use that with `fetchAll`, only with `fetch`:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)) {
    // Both of these will work
    $username = $row['Username'];
    $username = $row->Username;
}
```

If you really want to use `fetchAll`, you'll have to fetch the rows as one type and cast them back and forth between arrays and objects:

```
foreach ($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    // with PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, $row is an array
    $username = $row['Username'];

    $row = (object)$row;
    // $row is an object now
    $username = $row->Username;

    $row = (array)$row;
    // $row is now an array again
    $username = $row['Username'];
}
```

Comment: Did you read my comment actually?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Your first comment about how neither mysqli or PDO would allow this, yes. Your second comment about `FETCH_LAZY`, not really since I thought you were responding to a comment by @Dharman. I'd never heard of `FETCH_LAZY` so I wrote a quick test script to try that out, and it turns out that could indeed be the solution to OP's problem. I've updated my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You cannot get both at the same time. There would be no way to represent such a result in PHP.

When you try to use both with `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_OBJ` you are actually fetching the result as `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`. That's because fetch parameter is a bitwise flags parameter. When you do an OR operation on these flags it is the same as `2|5 = 7`. 7 is the value for `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`.

I don't know what use case you have for this, but it sounds like an XY problem. If you use `fetchAll()` you cannot have it both as an array and an object. But if you are fetching it row by row with `fetch()`, you could fetch each row in a different way.

```
$res = $pdo->query("SELECT 1 as foo UNION ALL SELECT 2 as foo");
var_dump($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
var_dump($res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
/*
Outputs:
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(1)
}
object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  int(2)
}
*/
```